# Gutenberg Editor Outside of Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

The new wordpress editor is really cool at least I think so. I'm wondering if there was a way to get it for a plain HTML project or as like a package? So far looking around I've only found it associated with wordpress.

If not then does anyone know of anything similar, preferably free but not required.

I have managed to find this, https://innovastudio.com/ its pretty similar but pricey.

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam._

Comment: CKEditor? It's used in Drupal and TYPO3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help: It seems to be a port from the wordpress editor

https://github.com/youknowriad/standalone-gutenberg

<strike>And then there is the contendor [Aloha Editor](https://www.gentics.com/genticscms/software_alohaeditor.en.html) (since 2010)</strike>
EDIT: (Link is dead) /EDIT

Answer (score 1):

There is now a package for Laravel that allows easy the implementation of the editor found here:

https://github.com/VanOns/laraberg/tree/d99c7ec34e2ff0bc4c9a7b81990841e6535862a6#installation